# Time Limit Exceed in KnapSack by Top Down Approach

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have written Java code to solve the below problem on Spoj.com but it's giving me "Time limit exceeded". I don't know why it is happening, I already did too much optimization.

> The famous knapsack problem. You are packing for a vacation on the sea side and you are going to carry only one bag with capacity S (1 <= S <= 2000). You also have N (1<= N <= 2000) items that you might want to take with you to the sea side. Unfortunately you can not fit all of them in the knapsack so you will have to choose. For each item you are given its size and its value. You want to maximize the total value of all the items you are going to bring. What is this maximum total value?
>
> Input
>
> On the first line you are given S and N. N lines follow with two integers on each line describing one of your items. The first number is the size of the item and the next is the value of the item.
>
> Output
>
> You should output a single integer on one like - the total maximum value from the best choice of items for your trip.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 4 5
> 1 8
> 2 4
> 3 0
> 2 5
> 2 3
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> 13

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {


public static int max(int a,int b)
{
return a>b?a:b; 
}
    public static int dfs(int W,int nxtIdx,int[]weight,int []value,int [][]m,int N)
    {

        int s=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if(nxtIdx>N)
            return value[nxtIdx-1];
        if(m[nxtIdx][W]!=-1)return m[nxtIdx][W];
        for(int i=nxtIdx;i<=N;i++)
        {

            if((W-weight[i])>=0 )
            s=max(s,dfs(W-weight[i],i+1,weight,value,m,N));


        }   
        if(s!=Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        {

            s=s+value[nxtIdx-1];


        }
        else
        {
            s=value[nxtIdx-1];

        }
        m[nxtIdx][W]=s;
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {


         int value[];
        int weight[];
         int W=0,N=0;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
        W=Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        N=Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
         int m[][]=new int [N+1][W+1];
    value=new int [N+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=W;j++)
            m[i][j]=-1;

    }
        weight=new int [N+1];
        value[0]=0;
        weight[0]=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)
        {
            String input[]=br.readLine().split(" ");

            value[i]=Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
            weight[i]=Integer.parseInt(input[0]);

        }

        System.out.println(dfs(W,1,weight,value,m,N));



    }
}
```

Comment: You need to memorize all your recursive calls.

Comment: I am doing that already

Comment: You knapsack approach is not correct.

Comment: but i have submitted through same approach on other places and my all test cases are accepted,pls tell me any case where the logic is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I can't access SPOJ right now.
Can you try this DP approach:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= W; ++j) {
                if(weight[i] > j) {
                    m[i][j] = m[i - 1][j];
                }
                else {
                    m[i][j] = max(m[i-1][j], m[i-1][j-weight[i]] + value[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: now it is saying wrong ans,hey my logic is all fine i think ,in your case res=max(res,s) so why are u returning s ,you should return "res"

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/7118667/ 
please look at this submission on different platform having same concept

Comment: Time limit is too low on this problem.

Comment: Just use DP to write it.

Comment: I dont know why I will try using c++. but 1 thing is sure the logic I have submitted is correct beacuse same logic I submitted in 3 platform and all accepted. I can saw people comment that top down is working but mine is not working :(

Comment: Use DP. It is simpler. Your code runs in O(n^3). It is W * N * (iteration inside your recursion `for(int i=nxtIdx;i<=N;i++)`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134920/discussion-between-rasul-kerimov-and-beer-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simple algo:

```
 class KnapsackWithTopdown {

    public int solveKnapsack(int[] profits, int[] weights, int capacity) {
        int[][] dp = new int[weights.length + 1][capacity + 1];
        return this.knapsackTopdown(dp, profits, weights, capacity);
    }

    private int maximum(int x, int y) {
        return x > y ? x : y;
    }

    private int knapsackTopdown(int[][] dp, int[] profits, int[] weights,
            int capacity) {

        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
            dp[i][0] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < capacity; j++)
            dp[0][j] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= weights.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= capacity; j++) {
                if (weights[i - 1] <= j) {
                    dp[i][j] = maximum(profits[i - 1]
                            + dp[i - 1][j - weights[i - 1]], dp[i - 1][j]);
                } else {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[weights.length][capacity];
    }
}
```